# change button text and icon file (font awesome) on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the text of a button, as well as its associated icon file on click, and then reverse that on click again. I have got half way there and am able to toggle the class of the icon and the colour of the button, however if I try to change text or html of button it removes the icon reference. Is there a more efficient way to get this all done

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="newSale">
    <i id="iconChange" class="fa fa-plus"></i> add new
</button>
```

.js

```
$( "#newSale" ).click(function() {
  $( "#openNewSale" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     $('#newSale').toggleClass('btn-success').toggleClass('btn-danger');
     $('#iconChange').toggleClass('fa-plus').toggleClass('fa-minus');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the display state of `openNewSale` using `if($("#openNewSale").is(":hidden"))` and change the classes accordingly

```
$( "#newSale" ).click(function() {
  $( "#openNewSale" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     $('#newSale').toggleClass('btn-success').toggleClass('btn-danger');
      if($("#openNewSale").is(":hidden"))
      {
            $( "#newSale" ).html('<i id="iconChange" class="fa fa-plus"></i> add new');      
      }
      else
      {
          $( "#newSale" ).html('<i id="iconChange" class="fa fa-minus"></i> remove'); 
      }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/47/)

Comment: That is essentially doing the same thing I am doing right now but with more code. The main thing I need to add is to change the text of the button while preserving the icon

Comment: Actually kind of used your code but changed the jquery calls of `$('#iconChange').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');` to `.empty().html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add new');` and then the reverse in the else statement. Got me there

Comment: Funny I just responded the same